# How to use setm in puppet

Tags: jboss7.x, puppet, jboss-eap-6, puppet-enterprise, augeas

I would like to change a one property name ( "**modcluster.proxylist**" ) with ***setm*** Command in Puppet. My following code is not working. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    augeas { "jboss_domain_config":
            incl    =>      "/opt/domain.xml",
            lens    =>      "Xml.lns",
            context =>      "/files/opt/domain.xml",
            onlyif  =>      "match /files/opt/domain.xml/domain/server-groups/*/system-properties/*/#attribute/name modcluster.proxylist"
            changes =>      "setm /files/opt/domain.xml/domain/server-groups server-group[.]/system-properties/property[.]/#attribute/value kumaran",
    }
```

Following is my Source XML which i would like to change.

```xml
<server-group name="ServiceGroupOne" profile="full-ha">
    <system-properties>
            <property name="jboss.default.multicast.address" value="232.0.2.20" boot-time="true"/>
            <property name="modcluster.proxylist" value="192.168.79.77:7777" boot-time="true"/>
            <property name="modcluster.lbgroup" value="SearchGroupOne" boot-time="true"/>
    </system-properties>
</server-group>
<server-group name="ServiceGroupTwo" profile="full-ha">
    <system-properties>
            <property name="jboss.default.multicast.address" value="232.0.2.20" boot-time="true"/>
            <property name="modcluster.lbgroup" value="SearchGroupTwo" boot-time="true"/>
            <property name="modcluster.proxylist" value="192.168.79.77:7777" boot-time="true"/>
    </system-properties>
</server-group>
<server-group name="ServiceGroupThree" profile="full-ha">
    <system-properties>
            <property name="modcluster.lbgroup" value="CommonSearchGroup" boot-time="true"/>
            <property name="modcluster.proxylist" value="192.168.79.77:7777" boot-time="true"/>
            <property name="jboss.default.multicast.address" value="232.0.2.20" boot-time="true"/>
    </system-properties>
</server-group>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a few problems in there. Let's deal with them one by one:

- it seems the `domain.xml` code you provide is wrong, as there's no `domain` and `server-groups` nodes as your Puppet code suggests. I take it there's two more levels around the code you provided:

  ```
  <domain>
    <server-groups>
      <!-- the rest of the file -->
    <server-groups>
  <domain>
  ```
- there's no need to set `context` when using `incl` and `lens`, it's automatic
- you misunderstood the way `setm` works: the first parameter is the nodeset on which Augeas will loop, the second one is the subnode to set and the third one the value
- the change you want to do with `setm` is inherently idempotent, there's really no need to use `onlyif` here.

Here's the result:

```
augeas { "jboss_domain_config":
  incl    =>      "/tmp/domain.xml",
  lens    =>      "Xml.lns",
  changes =>      "setm domain/server-groups/server-group system-properties/property[#attribute/name='modcluster.proxylist']/#attribute/value kumaran",
 }
```